# How do I set a variable in the configuration file setting.php and use it from code?

Tags: configuration

How do I set a variable in the configuration file setting.php and use it from code?

Answer (score 27):

in settings.php:

```
$conf['yoursite_something'] = 5;
```

Then, in your code:

```
// Second argument is the default.
variable_get('yoursite_something', NULL);
```

Make sure to prefix the variables, either with the module you're using it in or with the site name.

Answer (score 5):

Do note that it is not required to declare persistent variables in settings.php. You can simply call variable_get() from your code and define a default value in case the variable is not set. For instance, the following code will say hello on every page request as long as the 'mymodule_say_hello' variable is not explicitly set to `0`:

```
<?php
function mymodule_init() {
  // Get the mymodule_say_hello variable or use 1 if it's not set. 
  if (variable_get('mymodule_say_hello', 1)) {
    drupal_set_message('Hello world');
  }
}
?>
```

If needed, your module could publish a form that allows the admin to turn of this feature (the [system_settings_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module/function/system_settings_form/6) function makes that really easy) or you could change the settings programmatically by calling `variable_set('mymodule_say_hello', 0)`.

Answer (score 4):

## Drupal 8

In your settings.php:

```
$settings['foo'] = 'bar';
```

In your code:

```
use Drupal\Core\Site\Settings;

Settings::get('foo', 'mydefaultvalue');
```