# why some PDOException errors are displayed in details on users screen and some other not

Tags: 7, database, security

A user reported to me seeing the following error on his screen:
[image: PDOException max_user_connections]

The watchdog entry for this error looks like this:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction: INSERT INTO (.............)
```

I would like this kind of errors not to be displayed in detail on user screens.

However, I am not able to replicate this problem of displaying error in detail on the screen. During my tests, SQL errors are ***NOT*** displayed in detail at all. So, even if I apply a solution (like setting display_errors to FALSE in settings.php) I won't be able to test it, because I can't replicate this particular scenario which causes errors to be displayed on screen with details.

As part of the testing, I've made a deliberate mistake (in table name) in a database query in mymodule_node_view to test how such error will be visible on user screen. The problem is that in both cases, whether display_errors is turned "on" or "off" (checked on Site Status report: `http://example.com/admin/reports/status/php`), the result is identical. On user screen the error is displayed as:

[image]

It's not displaying any details, although  in the watchdog log, it is similarly also a PDOException:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydb.nodeaa' doesn't exist: SELECT (..............)
```

So, I don't understand. Why is Drupal displaying details of some PDOExceptions on user screen and not displaying details of some other PDOExceptions? How to effectively check whether a setting (e.g. display_errors set to "off") will fix the problem for all sorts of PDOException?

Comment: Similar question was posted [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36192/hide-errors-from-users-but-show-to-admin) - if your concern is essentialy different somehow, please help me understand what you need that's not already there.

Comment: Check this it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000336/how-to-debug-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded

Comment: It will solve your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175850/drupal-sql-timeout-error

Comment: @Mołot - I have the "Error messages to display" already set to "None" in Drupal and some of the PDOExceptions are displayed despite of it (as in the first screenshot). Currently I need to prevent all PDOException to be seen by anybody (user, anonymous, admin) and maybe then I'll think how to show them only to admin, but that's not a priority.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is - error that gets displayed means "Hey, I cannot connect to database! To many users already!". And the setting you are using to prevent error display are in database. And watchdog's log is in database. That's why Drupal shows it - it cannot know you set it not to, the very error prevents it from knowing. And even if it could, it cannot log it in any other way than to user's screen

To get this sorted out, you need two things:

- database-independent log module, like [File logging](http://drupal.org/project/filelog)
- [set variables responsible for not showing alerts in settings.php](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3307/how-do-i-set-a-variable-in-the-configuration-file-setting-php-and-use-it-from-co)

Comment: And if you'll ask how to solve the sql 1203 state itself, if it wasn't asked here yet, I can provide quite a few pointers. Just not in this question, for clarity.

Comment: This is working indeed! I managed to replicate this exact error on my local server and it threw all the details to the screen as before. Then I added to settings.php  `$conf['error_level'] = 0;` and the error was gone from the screen. [This post](http://drupal.org/node/1056468) was also useful.